# Green files won't copy

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption

I have a number of files in a folder that I want to back-up but Windows 7 won't let me. It says Access Denied. I was able to remove the green colour (encrypted) from the parent folder but trying the same thing on the files (via Advanced Properties) isn't working. I can clear the Encrypt checkbox for the file but then when I try to apply those changes, it says I need to provide administrator permission (I'm already an administrator with full access). If I click on Continue, it says Access Denied. If I then choose Try Again, it just keeps repeating the same message. If I click on Ignore, it just does exactly that and acts like I haven't tried to apply the changes.
What else can I do to give myself access to copy these files?

Answer (score 2):

As it seems you're aware based on your question tags, green files in explorer are encrypted.

The thing is that files can only be decrypted by the user who encrypted them. The key needed to decrypt those files is protected by that user's password.

**Note that force resetting the user's password will not allow you to decrypt the files, it will in fact render them unrecoverable.**

To determine who created the files, try checking the owner:

1. Right click the file.
2. Click properties.
3. Click the Security tab.
4. Click Advanced.
5. Click Owner.

Unless it was changed, the owner will be the user who originally created the file.

If the owner is the Administrators group or Domain Admins, then the file was created by a member of that group.

Once you know who created the files, log in as that user to decrypt them.

Comment: Actually, I'm the owner. I'm just stumped as to why I can't copy my own files. I don't even know how they ended up becoming encrypted.

Comment: Are you actually listed as the owner? Did you ever force reset your password?

Comment: Apparently, the owner is me but was created on my old computer. I just got a new computer about one week ago (the old one's motherboard died) and I installed the hard drive into my new computer. The owner would appear to be my administrator account from my old computer but if I try to add myself as administrator on my new computer, it stops me from doing so because it says "You must have access to the file and Write or Modify permission for it.

Comment: That would definitely cause a problem. If this is your System/C: drive (from the old computer), then you still have a chance. To do that, you need to try to boot from the old hard drive. There's also a chance that it won't work because of driver problems (storage driver in particular), but that intact system drive is the key to ever being able to recover those files.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't the C: drive. It was a separate hard drive. I transferred 3 hard drives into my new computer and the files that are causing the problem are on one of those hard drives. But it's odd that only certain files are affected.